# magento - default attribute set when making new products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

i have several attribute sets in my magento store. (v. 1.6.2)

When i make a new product "**socks**" is the default attribute set. But i would like "**clothing**" to be the default.

How can i change this?

I hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original question didn't seem to get answered here and I was looking for what Ronny also wanted.

Found there has been an extension released that does it simply for you.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/default-attribute-set.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. You should create new product.

Comment: i dont mean changing a products attribute set .... but the default attribute set before you start making a products

Comment: But it is possible to change a products attribute set ...
You need the : Flagbit Change Attribute Set extension (free, from Magento Connect)

Comment: I spoke about default magento functionality

Answer (score 0):

To change an existing product attribute set, you can [Create a new Attribute Set](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configurable-product-step-2-create-the-attribute-set) that contain all the attributes you need

You can either install this extension ([Change Attribute Set](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-change-attribute-set.html)) or make the changes in the database (you will need to know the products id and attribute set id)

To manually change (Always backup before making changes):

Go to eav_attribute_set table and look for the attribute_set_id of the newly create attribute set (you could also get this in the admin by look at the url www.xxxx/edit/id/10/key/xxx on Edit Attribute Set 'xxxx' page)

After you have a list of all the product ids and corresponding attribute set ids, then go to the table below and update those fields

```
Table Name : catalog_product_entity
Field Name : attribute_set_id
Field Name : entity_id // is product_id
```

Another way is to delete those product and recreate using the new attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to accomplish what you want by editing the database directly. *Only do this if you are comfortable with MySQL commands or another tool like phpMyAdmin.*

To make this change you will need to do two things.

1. Get the ID of your new attribute set, in this case your "**clothing**" attribute set.  You can locate the id in the `eav_attribute_set` database table or in the browser URL when editing the attribute set from the Magento admin area. I prefer to just use the database since we need to go in there anyways to make the change.
   `Table Name : eav_attribute_set`
   `Column Name: attribute_set_id`
   Look for the row in the table that has the name you used when you created the new set - it should be pretty obvious, you'll see all the attribute set names in the column called `attribute_set_name`
2. Once you have the preferred attribute set ID you then need to visit the `eav_entity_type` table and update the value in `default_attribute_set_id` column for the row where`entity_type_id = 4` and `entity_type_code = catalog_product`. In a fresh installation of Magento, the value to look for in this column is also 4.
   `Table Name : eav_entity_type`
   `Column Name: default_attribute_set_id`
   **Done!** Once you've changed the id value you will notice your preferred attribute set is the one selected by default the next time you go to create a new product. I believe this is what the question was asking for.

*NOTE: This should work for both Magento 1 and 2. At the time of writing this post the current Magento versions are: 1.9.2.4 and 2.0.7*

Comment: what is the error in this code : UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = '9' WHERE `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` = 15,14;   for single id its working, when i add more than one, its not working.